# React Error: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am getting below error:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `App`. 
See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:39295:25
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:197:91
```

Here is my code:

```
function Table({ countries }) {
  return (
    <div className="table">
      {countries.map(({ country, cases }) => {
        <tr>
          <td>{country}</td>
          <td>
            <strong>{cases}</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: A good title should communicate the problem not that you have a problem and need help, as that's assumed since you're on Stack Overflow asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you are not returning element iterating the countries. React throws an warning if you do not provide key for each element you render within the loop as. Key is needed for react to identify which element has been changed. You can pass index to the key as the country or the cases can be same.

```js
Table({ countries }) {
    return (
        <div className="table">
            {
            countries.map(({country, cases}, index) => {
                    return (
                      <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{country}</td>
                        <td>
                            <strong>{cases}</strong>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    )
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you can use the index, as long as your rows are not moving.  It caches some of its work to speed up on repeated renders, which happen a lot.  Row 47 this render, will be assumed to be row 47 last render.  If you went and inserted or deleted row 31, the next time, React will be able to tell, so it just recalculates it all.  For ALL the items in your huge table, from item 31 to the end.  For EVERY keystroke.  Slow.

On the other hand, if you use the Country name as the key, you can completely rearrange all your rows (sort by name, sort by pop) and React's cache will work.

Answer (score 6):

React requires keys or any element rendered in this fashion. The `key` is just an arbitrary, yet unique property, so pick something that fits that, like:

```
countries.map(({country, cases}) => {
  <tr key={country}>
     <td>{country}</td>
     <td>
       <strong>{cases}</strong>
     </td>
  </tr>
})
```

So long as the country names are unique it'll be fine. You may want to use something like a short-form [ISO country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) to avoid the whole mess with accents and spelling.

Answer (score 1):

The warning:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

is telling you that you have not provided a **unique key** prop to the list you made using `.map`.

Key can be any **locally unique** value. Read more [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Here are few examples:

```
// wrong
<div>
{
  [1,2,3,4,5].map(num => <p>{num}</p>)
}

// Correct. Good.
{
  [1,2,3,4,5].map(num => <p key={num}>{num}</p>)
}

// Correct. Not so good.
{
  [1,2,3,4,5].map((num, index) => <p key={index}>{num}</p>)
}

// Correct. Bad.
{
  [1,2,3,4,5].map((num) => <p key={Math.random()}>{num}</p>)
}

// Wrong
{
  [1,2,3,4,4,4].map((num) => <p key={num}>{num}</p>)
}

// Correct
{
  [1,2,3,4,4,4].map((num, index) => <p key={index}>{num}</p>)
}
</div>
```

So, to fix your code:

```
{countries.map(({ country, cases }) => {
  return <tr key={SOME_KEY_HERE}> { /* Maybe, key={country} or key={countryID} */ }
    <td>{country}</td>
    <td>
      <strong>{cases}</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

React requires that you need to have a `key` prop that differentiates elements in a loop

```
function Table({ countries }) {
  return (
    <div className="table">
      {countries.map(({ country, cases }) => {
        <tr key={country}>
        <!-- or key={Date.now()}, if your countries are not unique -->
          <td>{country}</td>
          <td>
            <strong>{cases}</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Table({ countries }) {
    return (
        <div className="table">
            {
            countries.map(({country, cases}, index) => {
                    return (
                      <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{country}</td>
                        <td>
                            <strong>{cases}</strong>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    )
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```