# Fixing the problem with a unique keys prop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am having a problem  console `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` which is messing with my cart functionality I have created a copy of it https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-http-8yhkp

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import './Home.css'
import Books from './Books'
import { BookContext } from "../../context/books";
const Home = () => {
   const {data, handleSelectCategory, currentSelectedCategory } =useContext(BookContext)
    return (
        <div className='books__container' >
          <h1 className='categories'>Categories</h1>
            {Object.keys(data).map((key, index)=>{
            let books = data[key];
            return (
              <> 
              <span key={key} onClick={() => handleSelectCategory(key)} className='books__list' >
              {books[0].category}
              </span>         
             </>
              );})}
              <Books category={currentSelectedCategory} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Your CodeSandbox appears to be missing the _"code"_ part

Comment: you get the error because when you use the map you put the key on the span but you have the span surrounded with a fragment.... like this <> span with key here </> Get rid of the fragment tags you don't need them

Comment: Keys can be provided to `React.Fragment` (not to its shorthand), but in your code, you can remove fragment. See this answer to understand the keys : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66703936/2873538

Comment: @ It forgot to save the code my bad

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the key to the outermost JSX element. You can either

1. Remove the `<> </>` tags (Best choice)

```
return (
   <span key={key} onClick={() => handleSelectCategory(key)} className='books__list' >
     {books[0].category}
   </span>         
   )
```

2. Use `React.Fragment` to apply key prop

```
return (
  <React.Fragment key={key}>
   <span key={key} onClick={() => handleSelectCategory(key)} className='books__list' >
     {books[0].category}
   </span>
  </React.Fragment>         
 )
```